# how segmentation of an object by OpenCV and python when some edges aren't sharp

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I have some photos of some screws. I should segment screws for measurement purposing. for each type of screw, I can modify some parameters like threshold level and my code should work on other screws by that parameters as well. In some cases, the edges aren't sharp. what algorithm can be useful for this station?

- [image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i547d.jpg)
- [ideal result for image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GAQfA.jpg)
- [image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ1wS.png)

I need a mask that segments a screw from another area in the image